# how to add title to side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I have just created a side menu using library `SWRevealViewController` in IOS. I want to set title for my side menu when i click on side menu icon.

I tried the below code but it is not working.

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = @"My test title";
```

Here the MenuViewController is the Subclass of TableViewController

for example

[image: for example like the title "Myshopi"]

Comment: Did you check your viewDidLoad method is called at all?

Comment: At least give a link to the third party library you are using. Normally, `self.title` will work if there's a navigation controller embedded.

Comment: is not possible , we need to customize.

Comment: @BadalShah -- question is simple , how to add the title of UItableviewController not embed with navigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Choice-1**

in `TableviewConroller`

```
on your indexpath (0) , set as your title
```

**Choice -2**

```
remove the tableviewController and add one UIViewController and embed with tableView and UIlabel

-- UIViewController
  -- UIlabel
  --UITableview
```

Comment: vishwas parashar -- I was worked in SWL more than 10 projects , in here choice no-2 helps you , if you need anything related to this i will support u